# Grabbing HEX from URL - PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to do if somebody adds a hex value at the end of the URL, I can show them a certain page.

For example, say I have colors.com, I would like it so if somebody want to go to colors.com/FF0000, it would display that hex on the page. Is it possible to grab it from the URL and display it although I would like it to be hex values only.

Remove certain letters and special characters so somebody can't just use text.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "Hope that makes sense." Nope. "display that hex on the page" Do you mean it would display the page in that colour? or just display the text?

Comment: @AlexThomas both. So I can add an inline style to the body tag of that color and have it as text. So if I went to /FF0000 it would have a red background with the text #FF0000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use your web server's URL rewriting to match patterns which look like hex colors (6 letters A-F and digits 0-9) and route accordingly.

Apache mod_rewrite example to silently rewrite `example.com/AA00FF` to `example.com/index.php?color=AA00FF`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# [A-Fa-f0-9]{6} matches six letters A-F and digits 0-9.
RewriteRule ^([A-Fa-f0-9]{6})$ index.php?color=$1 [L]
```

In your PHP script `index.php`, retrieve it from `$_GET['color']`.  You will need to validate it in PHP for that regex as well. Otherwise, you risk XSS attacks:

```
// You MUST validate it in PHP as well, to avoid XSS attacks when you insert it into HTML
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]{6}$/i', $_GET['color'])) {
  // ok to use
}
else {
  // Invalid hex color value. Don't use it!
}
```

I'm not saying this is a good idea, but to set the body color, you can then just do:

```
// Last warning: DON'T DO THIS UNLESS YOU HAVE VALIDATED WITH THE REGEX ABOVE!
echo "<body style='background-color: #{$_GET['color']}'>";
```

Comment: ([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}) if you also want to handle short hex notation

Comment: @user1505209 It's a bad idea because it means you can't reliably have _anyhting_ else on the screen without having to calculate a suitably visible text color for the background color.

Comment: And I can't help you if it isn't working, because you have not posted any code or given any indication of how you have tried to incorporate this.

Comment: Just noticed I was missing the `#` in the `background-color:` inline style, which would break the css.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Is it possible to hide this on a certain page? For example, I would like it so index.php has info and stuff on it and when they go to /ff0000, all that is on the page is the hex? I can echo the hex they go to but I don't know about having it on a different page.

Comment: @user1505209 You could do something like `if (isset($_GET['color']))` then only show the color, otherwise show everything as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the server is mapping the URL onto your script, you can get it from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

You can ensure it is a hex rgb colour with a simple regular expression.

Comment: I'm not using any script, just PHP.

Comment: PHP **is** a scripting language. Geez, try to know what you use!

Comment: All I have in my index.php in an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to grab it yes. This requires:

.htaccess file, something like this, in the root folder of colors.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

A index.php file containing something like:

```
// Get color from PATH_INFO in url.
$color = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1);
// If color is not a valid color hex code.
if(!preg_match('/^[a-fA-F0-9]{6}$/i', $color)){
    die("NOT VALID");
}

echo $color; // Prints 00FFFF if url is color.com/00FFFF
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Is there a way to change the not valid to something like a 404 page? And allow people if they went to color.com/#00FFFF?

Comment: Yes.. Just change die("NOT VALID") with your own needs.

Example: 

header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
die("<!doctype html><html><head><title>404</title></head><body><h1>404</h1></body></html>");

Comment: And what about allowing a hex in the URL?